# Power view in Excel Online, silverlight plug in

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, powerview

Hi I have an Excel document with Power View in Sharepoint Online and the different people that have access to the document (they open the document in an Android Tablet in Excel Online) have problems since the last Thursday because it show the following error: "Your browser doesn't support Silverlight. Please open this page in a different browser". I don't understand why this message appear, because they were working perfectly.